# Vue reactivity and VueUse computedAsync mistery

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity, vueuse

Would anyone have a hint as to why localData updates properly, while storeData remains stuck at -1 in this Vue SFC playground??

[Reactivity issue with computedAsync](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

The entire code is below; the real use case involves REST calls which are mocked here using `await timeout(3000);`

If I use `localData` and `storeData` directly in the template both update fine. If I go through the computeds however only the local data updates.
Interestingly enough if I use both `storeData` and `computedStoreData` in the template they both update fine.

```
<template>
  <h2>Test data from local: {{ computedLocalData }}</h2>
  <h2>Test data from store: {{ computedStoreData }}</h2>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import {computedAsync} from "@vueuse/core";
import {computed,  reactive, ref, type Ref, unref} from "vue";

const storeData = getTestData(3);
const computedStoreData = computed(() => storeData.value)

const localData = ref(-1);
const computedLocalData = computed(() => localData.value)

setTimeout(() => localData.value = 3, 2000)

// Store

const _testDatas = reactive<Record<number,  Ref<number>>>({});

function timeout(ms : number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function getTestData(venueId : number) {
  return computed(() => {
    if (! (venueId in _testDatas)) {
      _testDatas[venueId] = computedAsync(async () => {
        await timeout(3000);
        return venueId
      }, -1, {lazy: false});
    }
    return unref(_testDatas[venueId]);
  })
}

</script>
```

Edit: Even more interesting, adding this line makes it work:

```
watch(storeData,  () => {})
```

**[Edit 2]:** Maybe I should explain why I ended up with trying to dynamically create computed composables.
I have a dynamic set of venues that are obtained from the server:

```
venues = await fetchVenues()
```

Each venue then has a set of services:

```
venueServices = await fetchServices(venueId)
```

My components need the services for a venue, where the venue can be either static, or picked by the user, or supplied as the prop of a custom web component.

Obviously I want any given fetchServices call to happen at most once throughout the SPA for a given venue, and only if needed. I have tried several patterns but I can't come up with a robust working solution.

Comment: Composition api is primarily intended to be used only in component's setup body, any other possible usage needs to be confirmed. It's a mistake to use computedAsync inside computed, any kind of odd things can happen, that's the problem here

Comment: That really is a bit vague, could you elaborate? From the Vue docs on Composables: "The cooler part about composables though, is that you can also nest them: one composable function can call one or more other composable functions"

Comment: computed is not a composable but core composition api, composables conventionally start with "use", but there's no practical difference here. The problem is that you call something in computed's callback, it's not called immediately but called multiple times in the future, this is not how composables are supposed to be nested

Comment: It will only be called once since it's protected by if (! (venueId in _testDatas)). The docs have examples of nested composables (useMouse 2nd version), and of a composable being called "many times in the future", fetchData: https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables

Comment: (! (venueId in _testDatas))  is a hack that will work for one part. Another part is that it should run in setup body, this is currently not so. And yet another problem I don't mention is that side effects are made in a computed, computeds should contain no side effects like `_testDatas[venueId] =`. And again, computed isn't a composable and calling a composable inside its callback is a different thing and may lead to unexpected result, this is not what "nested composable" means. A computed can be expressed with a ref+watch combo. For a case that's beyond regular use of computed just use watch.

Answer (score 0):

I found a slightly different approach that seems to work (pseudo-code since I edited it to simplify):

```
type VenueArg = MaybeRef<number | HasVenueId | null | undefined>;
type ServicesById = Record<number, ServiceViewSlots>;
type ServicesByVenue = Record<number, Ref<ServicesById>>

const _servicesByVenue: ServicesByVenue = {};
 
export function venueServices(venueArg?: VenueArg) {
    return computed(() => {
        const venueId = _unwrapVenueArg(venueArg);
        if (venueId == null) return {} as ServicesById;
        if (!(venueId in _servicesByVenue)) {
            _servicesByVenue[venueId] = ref({})
            _fetchServices(venueId);
        }
        return _servicesByVenue[venueId].value;
    })
}

function _fetchServices(venueId: number) {
    epClient.getServices<ServiceViewSlots[]>(venueId)
        .then(r => {
            _servicesByVenue[venueId].value = r.reduce<Record<number, ServiceViewSlots>>((p, n) => {
                p[n.id] = n
                return p
            }, {} as Record<number, ServiceViewSlots>);
        })
        .catch(e => console.error("Fetch failed: " + e));
}
```